# Google Maps não está aparecendo

Tags: google-maps, ionic, maps

Estou com um problema com o Ionic, eu adicionei um mapa no meu app e ele não aparece, estou utilizando a interface Tab do Ionic, o código aparentemente esta certo, utilizei ele em um app Blank e ele funcionou, mas quando eu adiciono o mesmo código na tab do meu app principal ele não aparece.

Segue o código:

```
<ion-view view-title="Localização">
  <ion-content>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
            <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&sensor=true"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AccountCtrl">
        <ion-content scroll="false">
          <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
        </ion-content>

        <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
          <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate"></a>
        </ion-footer-bar>

        </body>   
    </html>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

fica só essa imagem branca [image: Clico na localização e o mapa não aparece]

Comment: Vendo sua pergunta fiquei curioso com a imagem: o que você está usando para testar no IE e mostrar multiplas versões de plataforma? Eu uso o Visual Studio para desenvolver, e teste no emulador Ripple no Chrome ou no emulador do Android que vem no Android SDK. O seu exemplo parece bem interessante.

Comment: Aproveitando, quando você compartilhar o seu código, evite compartilhar a sua key para o google maps, mesmo que seja apenas para testes, você pode omitir essa parte.

Comment: Você precisa editar o que está na pasta template dentro de www, Aquela index que aparece ali dependendo do caso não precisa mexer.

Answer (score -1):

Altere a altura do seu `#map`

```
  #map {
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
```